# Cannot kill running process

Tags: node.js

I have a TypeScript Express application inside an Ubuntu 20.x server and I just did a code update and when I attempt to run a `node build/app.js`, I get the following error:

```
> > node build/app.js
> 
> node:events:498
>       throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
>       ^
> 
> Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::8080
>     at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (node:net:1330:16)
>     at listenInCluster (node:net:1378:12)
>     at Server.listen (node:net:1465:7)
>     at Function.listen (/home/ubuntu/wmui/service-integration/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:618:24)
>     at Object.<anonymous> (/home/ubuntu/wmui/service-integration/build/app.js:70:5)
>     at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1103:14)
>     at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1155:10)
>     at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
>     at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
>     at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:77:12) Emitted 'error' event on Server
> instance at:
>     at emitErrorNT (node:net:1357:8)
>     at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21) {   code: 'EADDRINUSE',  
> errno: -98,   syscall: 'listen',   address: '::',   port: 8080 }
```

I run `sudo lsof -i :8080` and then get the pid and then run `kill -9 <PID>`, but that does absolutely nothing.

What next?

I have also tried this command: `kill $(lsof -t -i:8080)` and this command: `kill -9 $(lsof -t -i:8080)`

When I run another `lsof -i:8080` I no longer see it listening to 8080, it just says:

`node\x20/ 82822 user 21u IPv6 123456 0t0 TCP *:http-alt(LISTEN)`

Comment: After killing the process is the port still in use? Is that the port it's running on? Is the app starting up something else?

Comment: @DaveNewton, I added more info above, but I no longer see the port 8080 in use, but I continue to get the same message when I run `npm run build`.

Comment: You could try `sudo fuser -k 8080/tcp`

Comment: @AdamF, that does nothing either.

Comment: You're running the `node build` and the `kill` in the same console/on the same machine? Are there any other node processes running?

Comment: @DaveNewton, when I do an `htop`, there seem to be four running processes of the api, when I try to kill one, it just restarts it back up again.

Comment: @DaveNewton, I am running the commanda in the same Ubuntu server

Comment: Then there's a cluster being started up, or PM2-ish, or something that's restarting it.